# How to deal with doubt of Divorce?

Tags: doubts

Assalamualaikum

I have obsessive compulsive disorder. I naively believed that I said Kinayah word with the intention of divorce.

Later, I had doubts about whether I had intention or not because that incident was in the symptoms of obsessive compulsive disorder.

- Will this later doubt override the divorce I previously naively believed?
- Will divorce have a basis of consideration like worship where later doubts cannot override the certainty at the end of the process?

Answer (score -1):

Asalam Alikum,for me personally it is a bit complicated to answer your question. But why did you divorce? Are you a brother or sister?
Also did you wrong your wife/husband?
It is okay to have ocd its not your fault but have you ever thought of maybe going to a doctor to help out or talk about it with your sheikh?
Maybe your doubts aren't ocd is your wife/Husband being very rude/disrespectful or are they hitting you?

Note: Im not a sheikh or an Islamic teacher